# Facebook Like button not showing on Internet Explorer 7/8/9

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, xfbml

Facebook XFBML Like button doesn't work on IE9. I've read many answers and tried all solutions but nothing work, maybe my problem is different. I just see an empty space.

Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html
lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

The button works on Chrome without a problem.  I tried different combinations of attributes in the head and html tag but with no luck. Need your help.

**Update:** it seems that the iframe is there, but it has height and width equals to zero, as well as the surrounding span is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your parent container is not visible the moment the page is loaded?
I had that issue and the only fix I found was using the iframe version of the button.
But doing this, I removed the option to use the Edge.create events (Which I needed).

I you only want a Facebook like button, and no call to a different URL when the button is pressed, you could use the Iframe version